# Windows 8 and SDL/GLEW

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, sdl, glew

I installed Windows 8 CP, and realized my program crashes on runtime:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x771fe754 in MyProgram.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation.
```

I get this error when calling the following line of code:

```
glGenBuffers(NUM_VBO, VBOs_);
```

I am using the latest versions of both GLEW and SDL

The program runs fine in Windows 7, so I have no idea whats going on here...

Edit:

Note: `glGetError()` shows up no errors before the call to `glGenBuffers()`.

```
---------------------------
    GLEW Extension Info
---------------------------

GLEW version 1.7.0
Reporting capabilities of pixelformat 2
Running on a GDI Generic from Microsoft Corporation
OpenGL version 1.1.0 is supported

GL_VERSION_1_1:                                                OK 

// everything else is "missing"
```

Comment: Do you have any graphics drivers installed?

Comment: Just the one from windows update. I am using a macbook air 2011. "Intel Corporation driver update for Intel(R) HD Graphics Family (Microsoft Corporation - WDDM 1.2)"

Comment: @aCuria: Microsoft is notorius for poor OpenGL support. In the case of the drivers shipping alongside Windows and through Windows Update Microsoft actually *removes* any OpenGL ICD parts from the driver package delivered by the vendor.

Comment: This is rather bad... is there a workaround?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem - glew works fine but the intel drivers off windows update do not support OpenGL past v1. You
Can check what's supported using the utility that comes with glew.

After installing a better driver my issues were resolved. Note that doing this is not straight forward as they will not install normally. You have modify the inf file and re-sign the driver first. Which is beyond the scope of this question